# Misuse of the [objectmapper] tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The **objectmapper** tag states:

> ObjectMapper is a library for simple JSON object mapping in Swift.

That's very specific, and a search shows that there are 260 questions appropriately using the tags [objectmapper] [swift].

However, there are 419 results for [objectmapper] with [java] or [jackson] tags, none of which are specifying [swift]. Based on the tag description for **objectmapper** all of those questions are misusing the tag.

Initially tying the generic term "*objectmapper*" for object mapping to Swift was unfortunate, and the tag name **objectmapper-swift** with clear usage guidelines would have been better. But simply renaming the **objectmapper** tag to **objectmapper-swift** would make matters worse: having hundreds of questions that are nothing to do with Swift tagged with **objectmapper-swift** makes no sense at all.

A possible approach to partially address that concern would be to add a second new tag **objectmapper-jackson** for questions specific to Jackson's `ObjectMapper` class. Alternatively, just remove the **objectmapper** tag if the **jackson** tag is specified.

But either way, that would still leave a bunch of questions which needed to be manually resolved. For example: those currently incorrectly tagged [java][objectmapper].

I see the problem, but I don't see an appealing solution for ensuring that questions that are incorrectly tagged **objectmapper** get fixed.

Comment: Change the tag excerpt? To include both (something more generic) and prompt to user to also specify language/implementation

Comment: 260 swift questions VS 419 Java questions... Java wins. But seriously, just making the tag more generic about JSON to object mapping could work, it need not be tied specifically to languages. JSON serialisation/deserialisation is a problem solved for many languages and by many frameworks/libraries. Jackson is but one of many examples in the case of Java.

Comment: @Gimby there's already [tag:json-deserialization]

Comment: @Gimby & Knu The Jackson `ObjectMapper` isn't only about JSON either

Comment: @PetterFriberg you're assuming people actually read the tag excerpt. Spoiler alert: they don't. Take a look at any tag during a burnination process if you need evidence of that. There's an explicit "DO NOT USE" notice, but there's still questions asked with the tag.

Comment: I'd expect the 260 vs 419 to grow more to Java.  ObjectMapper has been sort of sherlocked due to Swift's built-in Codable mechanism, though [some people are still resistant](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper/issues/823).

Comment: @Zoe a diligent user like you do, unfortunately we can only optimize for that, anyway it will solve this tag easily and quickly ;)